# How to create a simple restful server / client solution in c#

Tags: c#, rest, server, client

I'm trying to create a server based around the restful api (basically a client - server system which listens on a specific port but all the tutorials I've seen were using asp.net, some databases or not suited / too complex. 
I've tried [The Msdn Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx), [That One CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/651995/Create-Csharp-Restful-Service-and-Consume-in-Cshar)  and That Other CodeProject Tutorial and also haven't found a simple solution here either.

I was thinking of a solution like:

Server listens on specific port for restful requests (Lets call it "ServerListener") and handles the request then in a static "CheckNumber" if its either positive or negative. It'll then reply to the client with the value "positve" or "negative" (depending on its value). The client then shows a MessageBox with the result.

The final idea would be having the server being proxied by an nginx server which handles the the encryption with the client and sanitizing the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my [post](https://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/), it contains several examples for simple REST server implementations, including C#, Java, PHP and node.js.

Comment: Broken link. Post still available somewhere else?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20180215021042/https://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364510(v=vs.85).aspx

The Http API will give you the freedom to implement your server without Asp.Net, without WCF, and even without IIS.